# How to make a call to server which is hosted from 2 urls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, nginx, hosting

I know the question sound very weird. I didn't know how to put my problem in 1 line.

So I have a react application that is hosted on http://my-application.com and is also accessible via http://some-domain.com/my-application

Using nginx, I have exposed 2 endpoints /whoami and /config

At runtime, I don't know by which url is the application is currently being accessed. I am making calls to /whoami and /config and they work when user has accessed application via http://my-application.com but it fails when user has accessed application via http://some-domain.com/my-application

To make it work for the later case, I have to make a call to /my-application/config and /my-application/whoami

Is there a standard way/library to solve this problem. I would want to avoid parsing current URL to know where to make the call. At least I don't want to parse the URL MANUALLY.

Note: the domain names and application names are just for example.

Comment: you can try to store the base path on app start every time in local storage. so it can be not possible which domain you working with if you allways access this variable if you need it.